# ajax PUT call fails with internal server error

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, spring-mvc, put

```
successs(userSurpriseResponse) { // success method of another ajax call

    var updateFeedbackSeenURL = "/" + contextName + "/service/updateseenfeedbacks/";

    var responseForSurprise = JSON.stringify(userSurpriseResponse);
    var surpriseResponse = JSON.parse(responseForSurprise);

    var feedback = surpriseResponse.feedback

    $.ajax({
        header: "Accept: application/json",
        url: updateFeedbackSeenURL,
        type: 'PUT',
        crossDomain: false,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data:JSON.stringify(feedback),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function() {
            alert("updated seenfedback");
        },
        error: function(xhr, ErrorText, errorThrown) {
            alert("failed inside seenfedback");
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

here, `userSurpriseResponse` from the server side is actually an object of `Surprise` class. The Surprise class has an attribute called `feedback`. Which in fact is an `ArrayList<FeedBack>`. I was trying to sent the entire arraylist back to server for some processing  required as per the scenario. When i send the call, I get an internal server `Errror( 500 (Internal Server Error)` ) with apache tomcat with the following log

```
*******************************************************************************************
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.tcs.teg.msgame.core.domain.FeedBack 
    at com.tcs.teg.msgame.server.dao.FeedBackDAOImpl.updateSeenFeedbacks(FeedBackDAOImpl.java:123)
    at com.tcs.teg.msgame.server.service.SurpriseBoxServiceImpl.updateSeenFeedbacks(SurpriseBoxServiceImpl.java:129)
    at com.tcs.teg.msgame.server.controller.SurpriseBoxController.updateSeenFeedbacks(SurpriseBoxController.java:40) 
*******************************************************************************************
```

The request mapping from the ajax call is handled by SurpriseBoxController.java as follows

```
*******************************************************************************************
from line no:40

@RequestMapping(value = "/updatefeedbackseen/", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    void updateFeedBackSeen(@RequestBody List<FeedBack> feedback) {
        feedBackService.updateFeedBackSeen(feedback);

    } 

*******************************************************************************
```

Comment: yes because this controller is not producing json. try returning json from this controller.

Comment: there's problem in your updateFeedBackSeen method exception says it loud

Answer (score 0):

solved it . The issue was evident in the console itself.My bad. The controller was expecting a List to map to the method. But i was receiving FeedBack[] (just Array). I changed the type to FeedBack[] as ( @RequestBody FeedBack feedback[])  and now it works fine @ the server side. But it returns a parse error text now. although it works fine at the back end .